# Flutter Listview where to onTap and how to make text and listview block larger?

Tags: flutter, listview

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

class SearchView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchViewState createState() => _SearchViewState();
}

class _SearchViewState extends State<SearchView> {
  List data = [];

  Future<String> getData() async {
    http.Response res = await http
        .get(Uri.parse("https://gcse.doky.space/api/schedule/buildings"));
    this.setState(() {
      data = jsonDecode(res.body)["result"];
    });

    return "success";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('건물 선택')),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Card(
            child: new Text(data[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am making lecture room reservation system.

But each listview block is too small so it's hard to click.

How to make text and block larger?

also where should I put onTap to make listview touchable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might I suggest you use a [ListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) instead of a Text?

```
  ListTile(
        onTap: _itemtapped,
        title: Text(myText)
  )
    

   void _itemtapped() {
      // do you thing here
   }
```

Comment: also to increase text size do this... Text(myText,style:TextStyle(fontSize:30.0))

Comment: wow It solved both problem. Thanks!
It automatically raised height and text size.

Answer (score 0):

Use `InkWell` widget. It will give you a nice tap effect.

```
InkWell(
 child: Text(data[index]),
 onTap: _onTap,
)
```

And implement on tap:

```
void _onTap() {}
```